# Matlab: sequential file loop

Tags: matlab, loops, import, sequence

I would like to loop the following script so that the 00001 will sequentially increase (to 00002, 00003 etc.) in the order 1 to 100. The 00001 appears 3 times:
Under `%% Initialize variables`: **r5004b_00001.dat** and under `%% Allocate imported array to column variable names`: **Angle00001** and **Intensity00001**

```
%% Initialize variables.
filename = sprintf('E:\XRD\Enamel\r5004b_00001.dat');
startRow = 5;

%% Format string for each line of text:
formatSpec = '%14f%f%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', '', 'WhiteSpace', '', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
Angle00001 = dataArray{:, 1};
Intensity00001 = dataArray{:, 2};

%% Clear temporary variables
clearvars filename startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the file name, this is a good idea, and here is the solution (I use concatenation for clarity only, `sprintf` is of course enough):

```
number = 3;
s = sprintf('%05d', number); % will produce '00003'
filename = ['E:\XRD\Enamel\r5004b_'  s '.dat'];
```

For the variables, [do not do this](http://www.mit.edu/~pwb/cssm/matlab-faq_4.html#evalcell). It is better to use arrays or, if you really like having many names, a structure with dynamic field names:

```
strct.(['angle' s]) = ...
```

If you really want to achieve what you ask for, it can be done with

```
eval(['a' s ' = 1 + 1;'])
```

Comment: How do you transfer the files in the structure to the workplace? I need to perform curve fitting and the data can not be toggled.

Comment: @Mosawi, I am not sure I understand you. What do you mean by "files in the structure" and "data cannot be toggled"?

Comment: The variables are confined within a structure array, I would like to transfer them to the main workplace. I am using the curve fitting app which can only select data directly from the workplace and not those in a structure array.

Comment: Then maybe you indeed need the last solution—with `eval`. I am not using apps yet, preferring to script everything for reuse and reproducibility.